# is there a PHP function to simulate how apache mod_rewrite works?

Tags: php, function, mod-rewrite

I'm pretty stuck in here, so what I need is a function or, an idea to create a function, to work pretty the same way as mod_rewrite of Apache.
It is supposed to have as param a regexp, writtten for mod_rewrite, and the url. Should return an array of parameters extracted from it.

Here's a short example of how it should work:

```
    function rewrite($regexp, $url){ 
           ....
    }

    $params = rewrite('([^/]+)-([^/]+).html', 'Oval-Shape.html');

    print_r($params);
```

The code above should print:

```
   array(1=>Oval, 2=>Shape)
```

Comment: You might be looking for [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: @AJ: There can be various reasons, why this could be of need.

Comment: @AJ Why I need this, is because somebody asked me to allow him to manually edit it's website urls, for seo purposes.  So I could't answer him "Learn Apache mod_rewrite"!!!. So I store the custom urls in database. But there's nothing new in here, Wordpress is doing the same way, matching urls with php and many other cms systems.

Comment: This cannot be considered as an answer ... but have you tried this service: [An easy way to test your RewriteRules](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/)? **P.S.** Found this link in some .htaccess related post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) uses a perl compatible regular expression. That's the same PHP does in [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

A difference is, that in `ModRewrite` you can prefix it with a `!` to not match something.

Another thing is, when you add the `NC` flag, they are case in-sensitive. In a PHP regex this can be achieved by using the `i` modifier.

So before you start re-invent the wheel, why not choose that function? It works like this:

```
$url = 'Oval-Shape.html';
$regexp = '([^/]+)-([^/]+).html';
$result = preg_match("({$regexp})i", $url, $params);
print_r($params);
```

And this is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Oval-Shape.html
    [1] => Oval
    [2] => Shape
)
```

So `$params[1]` is what you know as `$1` in .htacces and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to fully simulate Apache's `mod_rewrite` because Apache will rewrite the Url before dispatching the request, whereas when PHP is ivoked, the request has already been dispatched. For example, if you request

```
/index.php?page=mypage
```

with an `.htaccess` like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

You could also request the same Url with

```
/mypage
```

Which would result in `index.php` be called with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/mypage'` and `$_GET['page'] = 'mypage'`.This behavior cannot be replicated by PHP because Apache will not find `mypage` and will issue an error 404.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour can be easily replaced with PHP and allows more flexible and complex rules, for example based on database records.

Put this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

This way, every request is forwarded to index.php. You can then get and parse the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable and forward the page execution wherever you want to.

This is what every current MVC framework does. It's called routing.